# Bool function to check for a specific string requirement

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a program in which I must write a bool function that determines if a set of directions are valid input or not. The directions must be in the form of a number followed by a direction (N W E S). For example, a valid input would be 4N5S2W7E. I am totally lost on how to use the bool function to test if an input is valid or not. There may be no spaces and each number must be followed by a letter direction (and each letter direction must be preceded by a number). Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Comment: looks like you are asking for the code to validate the input string..post the code which you have tried so far so that one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well your function is only going to be part of the main function so for example

```
static bool CheckDirection(string s){
   // loop through each character in the string
   // check if char is an a-z and A-Z or if it's 0-9
   // compare next char and previous char
   // I'll let you figure out the exact logic here


    if (it is valid)
        return true
    else
        return false // If it's not right
}
```

Then in your main function you simply call

```
int main(){

    if(CheckDirection(string s)){

    }

return 0
}
```

Since the CheckDirection function is going to return a bool. You can just place it into the if statement directly.

Comment: What is the function to compare characters to one another in a string?